# Is it possible to get the manual cover picture of a Shared Album on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Even the v2.4 API returns the `cover_picture` as the first picture and not the acutal manually-selected cover picture. Whereas it presents the right one for normal albums. Shared Albums are relatively rare and consist of more than one contributor. The API also only shows the uploaded pictures that the user uploaded and not of the other contributor(s). The manually set cover picture is the user's own upload.

Perhaps it's a bug?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/298370576977192/

Comment: Oh well. 2014 February. I guess they have better things to do. Thanks anyway.